# Apex Batch : You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out

Tags: batch, scheduled-apex, apex, httprequest

I have a batch class that makes a external Http callout to create case records with a CreatePublicStuffCases() which is called in the start(). In the execute function, I have another  callout to get users details for specific cases that were previously inserted in the CreatePublicStuffCases(). Then at the end, do a DML to insert new account and also, update the cases that were previously inserted with thier respective case owners. I keep getting the error "System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out". Even when I tried doing the insert outside the loop with a List DML insert. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem**

Actually, webservice or http callouts and a DML won't take place in the same transaction. And that's why you are getting the error. [Read about this problem.](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003701&.)

**Solution**

1. You could break your code into two parts, as per the suggestion in the above article, Webservice part and the DML part.
2. Use [`@Future`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_annotation_future.htm) annotation. I had such problem and resolved using that.

**Code Sameple**     *This is just a out-of-mind code. but you need make changes or test this as per your need.*

```
//global variable at the top
Map<String,Object> mapObject;
//start ()
execute () {
      CallWebService();
      Map<String,Object> rawObj = mapObject;
      // Your remaining code
}

@future
public PageReference CallWebService() {
    // initialize the global variable.
    mapObject = new Map<String,Object>();


    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('GET');
    req.setEndpoint('https://www.publicstuff.com/api/2.0/request_view?request_id='+newReq');
    Http http = new Http();
    HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);

    String resonseBody = res.getBody();
    String jsonString = resonseBody;
    mapObject = (Map<String,Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString);
}
```

Comment: How would I break the code into two parts since I need to make two separate http calls?? Please see my updated code. thx

Comment: In the `execute( )` method of your batch, you can break your http callout to another method using `@future` annotation .
something like 
`@future
private void newReq(){ // your http call out from execute method }`

Comment: The problem is, I am using the List passed from the start function to generate a unique endpoint in my http callout. If its not done this way, then I cannot update the records correctly..

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code? where are you getting the error, in the `execute` or the `start`?

Comment: Yes I have debuged. The error is from the execute.

Comment: check the updates and see if the **Edit** gives you some direction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19319/discussion-between-mahmood-butt-and-codeslayer).